# Why does the "static" keyword makes the difference in CollectionView?

Tags: .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

I've built a CollectionView with Maui, this is the code:

```
//if I do remove this "static" keyword the code doesn't work anymore.
public static ObservableCollection<Test> _testing = new 
ObservableCollection<Test>();

public ObservableCollection<Test> Testing
{
    get => _testing;
    set { _testing = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test)); }
}
```

and here I add new data:

```
public IndexTest()
{
     Testing.Add(new Test{ name = "hello" });
}
```

This is the xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="OpenToursNative.Index"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:OpenToursNative.Test">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:IndexTest/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
          
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <LabelText="{Binding name}"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

If I run this code, everything works without problem, but, if I remove the "static" keyword on the ObservableCollection it doesn't log anything anymore.
Through the debugging it seems that every time I load the page the List counts 1 item, then after it loaded the List counts is 0.
I've wasted few days looking for a reason why it wasn't working at the beginning, adding "static" did the trick.

Can anyone explain to me why does the "static" keyword make this change?

Thank you all.

Comment: what specifically does it do wrong when you remove `static`?

Comment: The list doesn't log the data anymore. You can add as many items as you want, when you open the page to display them the list counts return 0 and it doesn't display anything.

Comment: when you navigate to the page it creates a new instance of the VM, so it will only display the items created in that instance.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I tried to add the items in the previous page, then I navigate to the Index page and the item shows up! The "static" keyword does the trigger, I just want to understand why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of `static` is fundamental to understanding c# code. It means that all the `instances` of that class **share** a single member (variable) with that name. Therefore, each time you navigate, that variable still contains whatever it had before.